# Appending regression slope to new vector

Tags: r, append, linear-regression

I have a large dataset of site locations and associated measurements/dates with variable length records. I would like to do a linear regression at each site and append the slope of the regression line as a new vector of my data.

Here's a simplified example of my data:

```
site_no<- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5)             
date<- c(1/1/1990, 1/1/1991, 1/1/1992, 1/4/1963, 1/10/1970, 1/10/1975, 
     1/10/1980, 1/1/1990, 1/1/1998, 1/1/1999, 1/1/2000, 1/1/2005)  
measurement<- c(.5, .75, 1.0, .5, .6, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.2, 1.8, 1.9, 2)   
df<- data.frame(site_no, date, measurement)
```

Bonus points if it's possible to eliminate single measurement sites, though I can deal with this easy enough before or after the fact.

I also have this data split into individual CSV files by site number, so perhaps its easier to approach the problem from that angle?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `library(data.table);setDT(df)[, Slope:=coef(lm(measurement~date))[2] , site_no]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go like this. A little manual, but transparent.

```
site_no<- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5)             
 date<- c(1/1/1990, 1/1/1991, 1/1/1992, 1/4/1963, 1/10/1970, 1/10/1975, 
        1/10/1980, 1/1/1990, 1/1/1998, 1/1/1999, 1/1/2000, 1/1/2005)  
 measurement<- c(.5, .75, 1.0, .5, .6, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.2, 1.8, 1.9, 2)   
 df<- data.frame(site_no, date, measurement)

 fit <- lm(measurement ~ site_no, data=df) 
 fit$coefficients[[1]]
[1] 0.2769231

 fit$coefficients[[2]]
[1] 0.3096154

  df$slope = measurement - (fit$coefficients[[2]]*site_no+fit$coefficients[[1]])

> df
   site_no         date measurement       slope
1        1 5.025126e-04        0.50 -0.08653846
2        1 5.022602e-04        0.75  0.16346154
3        1 5.020080e-04        1.00  0.41346154
4        2 1.273561e-04        0.50 -0.39615385
5        2 5.076142e-05        0.60 -0.29615385
6        3 5.063291e-05        1.00 -0.20576923
7        3 5.050505e-05        1.50  0.29423077
8        4 5.025126e-04        1.10 -0.41538462
9        4 5.005005e-04        1.20 -0.31538462
10       4 5.002501e-04        1.80  0.28461538
11       4 5.000000e-04        1.90  0.38461538
12       5 4.987531e-04        2.00  0.17500000
```